# Are $A,B,C$ coprime integers if $B=C$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, gcd-and-lcm, coprime

Let $A,B,C$ be three coprime positive integers, i.e., there exist six integers $λ_{1},λ_{2},λ_{3},λ_{4},λ_{5},λ_{6}$ such that

$$λ_{1}A+λ_{2}B=1$$

$$λ_{3}A+λ_{4}C=1$$

$$λ_{5}B+λ_{6}C=1$$

I am asking what happens if $B=C$: are $A,B,C$ still three coprime positive integers or not?

Comment: The only way that $B=C$ can be coprime to each other is if $B=C=1$.

Comment: Perhaps OP means what happens if $B=C$ and the three equations are true. The last equation would then imply $\lambda_5+\lambda_6=\pm1$ and $B,C=\mp1$.

Comment: @GregMartin: I am confused due to the answer below. It seems that there is 2 definitions.

Comment: It's analogous to this question [Should I use sets or tuples when dealing with linear dependence?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/201393/242). If $`A,B,C'$ denotes a multiset (repetitions allowed) then they are not pairwise coprime when $B = C$. Otoh, if it denotes a set then they are pairwise coprime since $\{A,B,B\} = \{A,B\}$. Usually one can infer from the context which denotation is intended.

Comment: @BillDubuque: As I understand, pairwise coprime imply setwise coprime

Comment: Yes, generally if $\,\color{#c00}{(a,b)=1}\,$ then $\,(a,b,c,\ldots) =(\color{#c00}{(a,b)},c,\ldots) = (\color{#c00}1,c,\ldots) = 1\,$ since [gcd is associative](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1189430/242). $ $ **Or** note $\,(a,b,c,\ldots)\mid (a,b)\ [\,\!\color{#c00}{=\!1}\ \text{here}]\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque: Merci bien

Comment: Note that I refer to *pairwise* coprime (vs. $(A,B,C)= 1$) since your "i.e. there exist ..." makes it clear that is what you use in your question. What is you context?

Comment: @BillDubuque: This is just an exercise of an exam.

Comment: Is that the entire exercise? If not, what is the rest of it? The more context you can give the better chance that you'll get an optimal answer for your context.

Comment: @BillDubuque: Merci. This is the whole text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends.

There are two conventions you can take. Let $S := \{a_1,\cdots,a_n\} \subseteq \Bbb Z$ be a set of integers. If you want to say the elements of $S$ are coprime, this can be interpreted two different ways:

- As a whole, they are coprime. This would mean that $\gcd(a_1,\cdots,a_n)=1$. That is, there are $\lambda_i \in \Bbb Z$ such that

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i a_i = 1$$

- Alternately, they are *pairwise* coprime. That is, $\gcd(a_i,a_j) = 1$ for all $i\ne j$. Or, put differently, there are integers $\lambda_{i,j},\mu_{i,j} \in \Bbb Z$ such that
  $$\lambda_{i,j} a_i + \mu_{i,j} a_j = 1$$
  for every $i \ne j$.

Suppose, then $S = \{A,B,C\}$. If $B=C$, and we don't "reduce" the set to the equivalent $S=\{A,B\}$, then $S$ is not coprime in the second sense (as $\gcd(B,B) = B$) unless $B=1$. However, it is in the first sense because

$$\gcd(A,B,B) = \gcd \big( \gcd(A,B)\; , \; B  \;\big) = \gcd(1,B) = 1$$